# When I use the helmet package on my free Heroku website, my CSS won't load and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, helmet.js

As the title notes, my website displays fine on Heroku until I try to use Helmet for security. I'm not sure why. Since it's a free Heroku tier, I don't have https enabled, I'm not sure if that's what's causing it - but curious if anyone here might know what it's happening.

This is my app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const helmet = require('helmet');

const viewRouter = require('./routes/viewRoutes');
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//SET SECURITY HTTP HEADERS
app.use(helmet());

//Body parser, reading data from body into req.body
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10kb' }));

app.use('/', viewRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: If helpful, the website is located here: http://www.precdent.com

Comment: Maintainer of Helmet here. If you're using the recently-released Helmet 4, this is probably happening because of the `Content-Security-Policy` header. You can learn more about CSP on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy), and you can mess with (or disable) the header in Helmet.

Not 100% sure that's the problem, but that is my guess.

Comment: Thanks Evan! I’m going to test it out.

Comment: I am having same issue today too. How do I disable the header in Helmet ? @EvanHahn

Comment: @HoangMinh You can set `contentSecurityPolicy: false` in the options. See the migration guide here: https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/wiki/Helmet-4-upgrade-guide#there-is-now-a-default-policy

Comment: Thanks Evan. I disable helmet for now on my project since I saw that you are going to revert the changes back to the way it was before in the next version.